# read a list by column

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have a list with numbers in it as follows:

```
['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,10,11,12']
```

I want to form a list by column. For eg:`1,5,9 in single list`
I have written a python code:

```
def readcolumn(userlist,columnName):
    for x in userlist:
        columnList.append(x[columnName])
    return columnList

data1=readcolumn(myList,1)
print(data1)
```

When I try to print the data. The output is as follows:

```
[',', ',', ',']
```

because value at index"1" is ",". I tried to strip ",".But then for two digit number it just prints the first character for example for "10" it just print "1". How can I solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 1-dimensional list with three strings. There are no columns. You need to split this into sublists. Then you can get columns with a simple comprehension:

```
l = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,10,11,12']
m = [item.split(',') for item in l]

[item[1] for item in m]
#['2', '6', '10']
```

Of course, if you want to do it in one step and discard the 2D list you can:

```
l = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,10,11,12']
[item.split(',')[1] for item in l]
#['2', '6', '10']
```